# Josso + LDAP integration

Tags: openldap, josso

Please answer me in the following question about JOSSO + LDAP integration.

I can use my user from ldap server for login into josso sso. I created ldap server add ldif file depends on official documentation

[JOSSO1/LDAP+Setup](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/LDAP+Setup)

After login i get this error message

```
DEBUG org.josso.gateway.signon.LoginAction - [AuthenticationFailureException] userName
```

org.josso.auth.exceptions.AuthenticationFailureException: userName
        at org.josso.auth.AuthenticatorImpl.check(AuthenticatorImpl.java:76) ~[josso-default-authenticator-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
        at org.josso.gateway.identity.service.SSOIdentityProviderImpl.login(SSOIdentityProviderImpl.java:201) ~[josso-default-identityprovider-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
        at org.josso.gateway.identity.service.SSOIdentityProviderImpl.assertIdentity(SSOIdentityProviderImpl.java:274) ~[josso-default-identityprovider-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
        at org.josso.gateway.SSOGatewayImpl.assertIdentity(SSOGatewayImpl.java:363) ~[josso-core-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
        at org.josso.gateway.signon.LoginAction.login(LoginAction.java:200) [josso-protocol-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
        at org.josso.gateway.signon.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:137) [josso-protocol-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484) [struts-1.1.jar:1.1]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274) [struts-1.1.jar:1.1]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482) [struts-1.1.jar:1.1]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525) [struts-1.1.jar:1.1]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.josso.gateway.filter.ProtocolHandlerFilter.doFilter(ProtocolHandlerFilter.java:103) [josso-protocol-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote1.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) [tomcat-coyote1.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote1.jar:7.0.65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_07]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote1.jar:7.0.65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_07]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. Problem was a josso-gateway-auth.xml file. In this file we have a `<basic-authscheme:basic-auth-scheme id="josso-basic-authentication" hashAlgorithm="MD5" hashEncoding="HEX" ignorePasswordCase="false" ignoreUserCase="false">` i changed hashencoding HEX to BASE64, and set for LDAP users MD5 password user with MD5.